# Can a single cell act as list with a delimiter?

Tags: excel

Currently i have this if statement and want to alter where the elipsis is. I had E1:E4 previously.

```
=IF(B2="StandardDoor",   ...    ,IF(B2="XDDoor",F1:F4,IF(B2="SR",G1:G3,
          IF(B2="SR3",H1:H3,I1:I3))))
```

But i want to change it to something like for example

```
=IF(B2="StandardDoor",   "3, 4, 5" , false)
```

where the drop down gives the output of 3 or 4 or 5 as options for when standarddoor is selected in B2

Comment: *where the drop down gives the output of 3 or 4 or 5 as options* do you mean you want this formula in a data validation dropdown?

Comment: @Plutian yes so i can chose 1 of these options

Comment: I would suggest using `{3,4,5}` or maybe `TRANSPOSE({3,4,5})` within the formula, but since this 365 update the formula overflows into three cells rather than staying in a single cell.

Comment: Forget my last comment - have a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1045133/how-to-create-a-named-constant-array-for-use-in-data-validation) answer.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook yeah i found that they both overflow.